# In CSS file where I applied 16px font size to whole html tag.but now when I am trying to change the footer size by .75rem the size is not changing

Tags: html, css

I applied **font-size: 16px** to the html tag but when i'm trying to change other tag's font-size, the fonts are not changing they are still at **16px**.
Below as it can be seen that html tag is set to 16px and at down below right there in the **footer .content** i applied "**font-size: 0.75**;" but font size is still same and at similarly little up there in **quotes-section quote** i tried to do the same thing but still i'm unable to change the size.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width," initial-width="1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Damion" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/reset.css">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Header -->
  <header>
    <div class="content">
      <a href="index.html" class="desktop logo">Fotomatic</a>
      <nav class="desktop">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Product detail</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/">Follow us <img class="icon" src="./resources/images/instagram.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <nav class="mobile">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="./resources/images/ic-logo.svg"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="./resources/images/ic-product-detail.svg"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="./resources/images/ic-about-us.svg"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="button">Join us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- Main Content -->
  <div class="main-content">

    <!-- Sign Up Section -->
    <div id="sign-up-section" class="banner">
      <div id="sign-up-cta">
        <div class="content center">
          <div class="header">
            <h2 class="cursive">Instant</h2>
            <h1 class="striking">FORMAT CAMERA</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="email">
            <span>
              Email us to request a demo and be in our waiting list for the <strong>Febuary 2017</strong> release!
            </span>
            <div class="button">Join the waiting list</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Features Section -->
    <div id="features-section">
      <div class="feature">
        <div class="center">
          <div class="image-container">
            <img src="resources/images/feature-1.png" />
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            <h2>Advanced, automatic, instant</h2>
            <h3>Shutter speed, apperture and flash output adjust automatically</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="feature">
        <div class="center">
          <div class="image-container">
            <img src="resources/images/feature-2.png" />
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            <h2>Beautifully crafted inside-out</h2>
            <h3>From the paint outside to the tiny screw inside, Fotomatic is crafted with love and 20-year of expertise</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Filters Section -->
    <div id="filters-section">
      <div class="content center">
        <h2>Over 20+ filters to choose from</h2>
        <h3>Feed your creativity with 20 different filter designed by our eclectic in-house photographers!</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="images-container">
        <div class="image-container">
          <img src="./resources/images/filter-1.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
          <img src="./resources/images/filter-2.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
          <img src="./resources/images/filter-3.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="image-container extra">
          <img src="./resources/images/filter-4.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="quotes-section">
      <div class="content center">
        <span class="quote">“It’s truly something that could create a brand new photography Renaissance”</span>
        <img class="quote-citation" src="./resources/images/photography-logo.png" />
      </div>
    </div>

      <!-- footer -->
      
    <footer>
      <div class="content">
        <span class="copyright">© 2016  Fotomatic, All Rights Reserved</span>
        <span class="location">Designed in NYC</span>
      </div>
    </footer>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
/* Universal Styles */

html {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  footer .content {
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 0.75;
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem;
  }
```

Comment: Please share html codes as well. But checking your CSS, quick question: Do your footer has the ```content``` class itself or it has a class ```content``` inside of it? If the footer itself contains that class then the selector would be ```footer.content``` without the ```space```

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about providing a [mcve]. What you've provided is neither minimal (it seems to be your entire stylesheet, not **just the parts needed to reproduce the problem**) nor enough to reproduce the problem (the HTML is missing).

Comment: okay i got it. i have edited it and also provided the html code along with the block of CSS code where I'm facing an issue.

Comment: The issue is `font-size: 0.75;` is missing the unit and is an invalid declaration. Should be  `font-size: .75em;` or `font-size: 75%;`

Answer (score -1):

```css
.content {
  font-size: 0.75rem; /* Add "rem" as the unit */
}

.quote {
  font-size: 12px; /* Add "px" as the unit */
}
```

Comment: The issue is `font-size: 0.75;` is missing the unit and is an invalid declaration. I guess this answer was downvoted for not explicitly stating that?

Comment: i think so this could be the reason. but i tried every possible ways but nothing came out